# I can't preview my code in Chrome via Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I got *view in browser* plugin and I tried to preview my html code in Chrome but it only works with Firefox.
Then i found [This guide](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser/wiki/Configuring-Browsers). I followed the instructions carefully and created a new file "**View In Browser.sublime-settings**" with a new settings:

```
{
   "selectedBrowser": "chrome"
}
```

But the plugin still open the preview with firefox. also i created a Build to open the preview with chrome but doesn't work. I have windows 7, 64-Bit.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the documentation says to use a setting `"selectedBrowser"`, when the plugin actually looks for a setting with key `"browser"` instead.

Modifying your `View In Browser.sublime-settings` file to:

```
{
    "browser": "chrome64"
}
```

should work if you have installed the 64 bit version of chrome.

It seems that you are not the only person with this problem - see https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser/issues/53 and https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser/issues/41 for details (including some other possible solutions/workarounds you can try if the above doesn't work for you).